# Apache2 slow CSS and Image update

Tags: php, css, apache, apache2

I am running a Apache2 server on my Debain 7.3 Dedicated VPS. For some odd reason the CSS files and Image files take forever to update when I change anything in them. What I have been doing to fix it I add `?<?php echo time(); ?>` after the object.

In example: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/css/stylesheet1.css?<?php echo time(); ?>">`

This seems to fix it but I really hate having to include that in every CSS and image file I add.

If you need more information please ask, I don't know what I need to include here.

I also use this thing called bind or something for the Domains. I don't remember the full name. I had someone else set this up a while back. I have always had this issue but I never felt like addressing it.

Comment: Can you open up your browsers debugger and post the `Response Headers` it sounds like you have something like `varnish` running

Comment: @cmorrissey I have no clue what a response header is. I can give you the link to the site? www.chillax-gaming.com

Comment: Your site is using `CloudFlare` which is caching these resources, you will need log into your account and set up page rules which will exclude the files you don't want cached.

Comment: @cmorrissey I changed it to 'chillax-gaming.com/*
Cache level: Bypass cache' But it still seems to happen. I changed the css real quick (after removing the php echo time) and refreshed and what I changed updated but then I changed it back and it didn't update.

Comment: what browser are you using? The browser is also going to cache this.

Comment: I am using Firefox. But after I did the change I went to firefox and refresh and it didnt change but then I went to Chrome and it wasn't changed either.  But now it has updated. Its seems to be always a short caching on the web server. which is annoying when you are editing files and what not.